# CakePHP-3.3 "maxLimit" for pagination is not working

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to limit the fetched rows.

```
public $paginate = [
    'limit' => 1,
    'maxLimit' => 2
];
```

Also tried with

```
$users = $this->paginate($this->Users, ['limit' => 1, 'maxLimit' => 2]);
```

I was expecting two rows in the result but I am getting three rows in the result. Currently I have only three rows in the DB.

Answer (score -1):

I think I got an explanation [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9446) why this is behaving like this and where I was confused.